# 'Command not found' when running .NET Core console in Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have downloaded .NET Core 3 (preview) and I have in Visual Studio 2019 (preview) created a hello world project consisting of class library and a console program.  The program runs on Windows.

I have Windows Subsystem for Linux running Ubuntu 16.04 and I install dot net so that dotnet --info returns something (non error).  Are there any other steps required?

If I go to my console apps binary folder and then shift+right mouse button click to get the 'Open Linux shell here' menu item and take that option then my Ubuntu window opens in the same directory as the console app executable.

From the bash prompt if I type the executable name (either with or without.exe) and of the correct casing it just reports 'Command not found'.

I am wondering what step I have missed.

Comment: How do you build/publish your application ? You might need to rebuild in bash first. To run a dotnet core app you can use `dotnet <MyApp.dll>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable name is not a known command to the shell. You need `dotnet <EXECUTABLENAME>`